# JQuery css() behaviour

Tags: jquery

Why these 2 instructions don't produce the same render please ?

```
$("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "width": $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().outerWidth() - 
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("padding-left")) - 
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("padding-right")) -
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("border-left-width")) -
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("border-right-width")) -
        24 + "px"
});
```

and

```
$("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("position", "absolute");
$("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("width", 
    $("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").parent().outerWidth() - 
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("padding-left")) - 
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("padding-right")) -
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("border-left-width")) -
        parseInt($("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("border-right-width")) -
        24 + "px");
```

in first case, `width` equals 500px and in 2nd case `width` equals 394px (as expected).

Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the position isn't absolute, the `j_idt14\\:panelGrid label` element is included in the `width` calculation of the parent element. My guess is that the `j_idt14\\:panelGrid label` element is wider than the parent.

When the element's position gets set to `absolute`, its width is ignored in the calculation since it's no longer contained within the boundaries of the parent.

Comment: thank you very much if I add `$("#j_idt14\\:panelGrid label").css("position", "absolute");` before first case above, it's work so this is a position problem in calculation. I'll use 2 css() instructions so. Ty again